# Are ArcGIS 9.3 layer files compatible with ArcGIS 10.1?

Tags: arcgis-10.1, arcgis-9.3

If I save layer files in ArcGIS 9.3, can they be opened and modified in ArcGIS 10.1?

When I try to open the layer file in 10.1, it does not work and gives me an error message: "the imported layer is in an invalid format."

Comment: Are you unable to open it in 10.1? Or is the problem when you then try to open it again in 9.3?